# Wicket - which ORM?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, wicket

I'm looking for an easy-to-use and intergrate ORM for Wicket application. I was thinking about Hibernate. Is it a good choice? What are the possible problems with Wicket/Hibernate? Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest EclipseLink over Hibernate because of some lazy-loading and relations related problems. Integration is basically the same.

With additional access layer actually any ORM should be easily pluggable.

Answer (score 6):

You should not tightly couple any ORM with wicket. Use spring or guice to manage your service layer (including ORM). Inject your service components into wicket using the wicket-spring or wicket-guice integration. If you do it that way, the choice of ORM is totally up to you. Here is a reference of [ORM technologies supported natively by spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html). (I'd go with JPA, as it's an open standard)

Answer (score 4):

Subjective. But yes, Hibernate is good choice it is very easy to integrate it with Wicket. Alternatively, you can for example think of JPA.

Fav. combo : Wicket-Spring-Hibernate

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at iBatis / MyBatis - it's a bit simpler to learn that Hibernate. But not true ORM - rather a SQL <-> DTO mapper.